# Adding a method to a prototype called 'speak'

Tags: javascript, string, function, object, ecmascript-6

Keep getting the error:

Should add a method to the prototype called speak

Expected 'DogsaysWoof' to be 'Dog says Woof'.

Thought I nailed it but something is missing. I put the spaces "" between the properties but it still comes up 'DogsaysWoof'. Think it is because I am missing a reference to the method to the prototype but it seems not to matter what I put in there. (Right now it is "says")

I'm a little flustered on this one.

```
function exerciseTwo(AnimalClass){
  // Exercise Two: In this exercise you are given a class called AnimalClass.
  // The class will already have the properties 'name', 'noise' on it.
  // You will be adding a method to the prototype called 'speak'
  // Using the 'this' keyword, speak should return the following string:
  // '<name> says <noise>'
  // DO NOT create a new class or object

  /*My ************************************************************** Code*/
  AnimalClass.prototype.speak = function(says){
    this.speak = 'says';
    return this.name + '' + this.speak + '' + this.noise;
  };
  // Please write your code in the lines above
  return AnimalClass;
}
```

Comment: You're adding empty strings, which are not spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually add the spaces - currently they're empty strings:

```
return this.name + ' ' + this.speak + ' ' + this.noise;
//                  ^                  ^
```

Comment: Wow. I cannot believe I missed that.  Been working 12 hours straight on these problems. Really appreciate you finding my mistake Jack. Thank You! It worked obviously.

Comment: No problem @DangerousWithRocks, if my answer fixed your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the grey tick mark to the left of my answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this with Template literals. You don't need worries about concatenation.

```
return `${this.name}  ${this.speak} ${this.noise}`;
```